# Flutter Firestore transaction not running properly

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to increase the no. of likes for a name whenever it is tapped. I have used the following cloud firestore query

```
onTap: () => Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
            print(Text('hello'));
            DocumentSnapshot freshSnapshot = await transaction.get(record.reference);
            Record fresh = Record.fromSnapShot(freshSnapshot);
            await transaction
                .update(record.reference, {'votes': fresh.votes + 1});
          }),
```

The above transaction is not reflecting any changes to the database.

Comment: Try checking your rules